# sort docker containers that have numbers in the name

Tags: sorting, docker, filter, scripting, containers

I have 3 containers running

- my_container_9
- my_container_8
- my_container_7

I just want the container with the lowest number in the name,
in this case

`my_container_7`

Any answer will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you try something at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this one

`docker inspect --format='{{.Name}}' $(docker ps -q) | grep CONTAINERS_NAME | awk -F  "_" '{print $NF}' | sort -n | head -1`

this script takes the lowest running container, if you want to get the lowest in all containers (running and stopped) just edit this part $(docker ps -q) like this  $(docker ps -a -q).

Answer (score 0):

Just use it it:

`docker ps --filter 'name=my_container_' --format '{{.Names}}' | awk '{print substr($1,14)}' | sort -n | head -1`

Let me know if it is enough. =)